# Best way to perform an airdrop?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, dapp-development

We have launched a pre-order token and are wanting to reward people for interacting with us. What is the best way to perform an airdrop to around 500 people if the token has already launched? Should we use a code with an interface to the token and would we need to make an array of 500 people or is their a limit? If there is already a code floating around at there that does this could I please have a link? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there addresses already stored in another contract?

Comment: No at the moment they are stored in a spread sheet. The contract doesn't have to be crazy complex I just want to basically send a few tokens to a tonne of address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways and variations to go about this. Based on your requirements, it'd probably be best to go with an Owner/Mediated Distribution.

This option would require you to simply create the token contract, either have the owner, or assign another account/contract as the distribution manager, and create a backend system that loops through and distributes the tokens to all addresses in your list.

You'd also have to have some checks and balances in place to make sure that they don't receive tokens again in case you need to run your backend system over.

*Please note that this method, you will be responsible for the gas cost.*

Example: https://github.com/KyberNetwork/airdrop

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This code looks like it would do the job but given that I have already deployed the token contract a few days ago is there something I should add to it so it interacts? E.g an input of the token address somewhere?

Comment: @darknightsy The airdrop code is actually separate and independent from the token code Check the `airdrops/contracts` directory. It just has to run from the same owner of the original contract. I recommend you testnet before deploying.

Comment: @darknightsy Also, since you are just in the prelaunch phase...if you don't have too many addresses in the preorder, it might be worth migrating all data to a new contract. I'm sure people wouldn't mind for free tokens!